# Bootstrap modal alignment of table

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a modal window which has 3 tabs. One one tab i tried to align the button and table on line  with other controls, but it dint work.

**HTML:**

```
<tab  ng-controller="elasticController"  heading="Data Source">
     <div class="row">
                         <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                             <div class="form-group"  >
                                 <label class="control-label col-lg-6 col-md-6">Data source</label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                                         <select  class="form-control" name="fancySelect" > 
                                    <option value="1"   data-html-text="Elastic search"> Elastic search</option>             
                                 </select>
                                    </div>
                             </div>
                         </div>                         
                       </div>
                       <div class="row">
                             <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group"  >
                                <label class="control-label col-lg-6 col-md-6">Enter the URL:</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                                      <input  class="form-control" />
                                </div>
                                   </div>
                             </div>

                       </div>
                        <div  class="row">
                             <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group"  >
                                <label class="control-label col-lg-6 col-md-6">Select the index:</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                                       <!--  <select ng-model="ser.type" ng-options="t.id as t.title for t in chartTypes"></select> -->
                                 <select ng-model="selectedIndex"  ng-options="p.index for p in indexes | orderBy: 'index'"  ng-required>
                                 </select>
                                </div>
                             </div>
                         </div>

                       </div>
                       <div  class= "row">                          
                            <div  class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                                 <button   ng-click="searchQuery()"  class="btn btn-default" >Get data</button> 
                             </div>

                       </div>
                        <div class="row">
                             <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                                 <table class="table">
                                                    <thead>
                                                         <tr>
                                                             <th ng-repeat="(header, value) in resultData[0]">
                                                             {{header}}
                                                            </th>
                                                        </tr>
                                                     </thead>
                                             <tbody>
                                                <tr ng-repeat="row in resultData">
                                                    <td ng-repeat="cell in row">
                                                     {{cell}}
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                              </tbody>
                                      </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>              
                 </tab>
```

Current: [image]

Desired:
[image]

Comment: You should use `col-md-offset-*` to align

Comment: @coung le, how to add a space between getdata button and the table

Comment: Simplest way you can add `<br>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because all other controls have a Label to fill the space at left side.

Change

```
<div  class= "row">                          
    <div  class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
        <button   ng-click="searchQuery()"  class="btn btn-default" >Get data</button> 
    </div>
</div>
```

To

```
<div  class= "row">                          
    <div  class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
        <div class="col-lg-offset-6 col-md-offset-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6">
            <button ng-click="searchQuery()" class="btn btn-default" >Get data</button> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not it has moved to left

Comment: @Sajeetharan This will work if you have a parent set with `col-md-6 col-lg-6` as other elements above are wrapped with parent element with `col-md-6 col-lg-6`

Comment: am using bootstrap 3. yes its a custom class

Comment: @anpsmn Exactly, I forgot to calculate that... Thanks.

Comment: i need to have a space between get data and table also the size should be the sam

Comment: @Sajeetharan I can't test it right now, but try to wrap the `<div class="col-lg-offset-6 col-md-offset-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6">` with a `<div class="form-control">` like the other controls...
Can't You provide a fiddle?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69434/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-vitox).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this page:
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal

Checkbox at the end and button is like you want.

Ithink you must add class controls to your table

EDIT:

You don't have to put all your items in a

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
```

part.

Just put all .form-group at the same level and use offset like said @cuong-le

your code must change from

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group"  >
            <label class="control-label col-lg-6 col-md-6">Data source</label>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                <select  class="form-control" name="fancySelect" > 
                    <option value="1"   data-html-text="Elastic search"> Elastic search</option>             
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>                         
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group"  >
            <label class="control-label col-lg-6 col-md-6">Enter the URL:</label>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                <input  class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
....
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                 ....                                
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

to

```
<div class="form-group"  >
    <label class="control-label col-lg-6 col-md-6">Data source</label>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
        <select  class="form-control" name="fancySelect" > 
            <option value="1"   data-html-text="Elastic search"> Elastic search</option>
        </select> <!-- YOU MISSED IT ! --> 
     </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group"  >
        <label class="control-label col-lg-6 col-md-6">Enter the URL:</label>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
            <input  class="form-control" />
        </div>
</div>
....
<div class="form-group">
        <table class="table control-label col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-md-offset-6  col-lg-offset-6">
            <thead>
                 ....                                
            </tbody>
        </table>
</div>
```

I think this works.
If you have trouble again create a jsfiddle, we can play !

Comment: OP is using Bootstrap 3 and you have linked to Bootstrap 2

Comment: you're right but there is exactly the same explanation with rigth attribute in the bootstrap 3 documentation http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal The div that contain the line must be .form-group and You can use you col-lg-... inside a new div before your table

Comment: Yes you can use `col-lg-*` but what works here is the `offset-*` class as OP is already using the `col-lg-*` classes. You are asking the OP to add class `controls` in your answer which won't work in this case.

Comment: what do you want to say with "OP" ?

Comment: I meant the Original Poster who started this thread. Removing my downvote for the corrections you did in your answer. You don't need a control-label class, offset is good enough.